# Board editor using customized pieces and board

Tags: software, chess-set

I'm looking for a program or website which offers to create chess diagrams using custom piece sets.

I know many sites and programs that offer this but with a preset types of pieces. This is the case for example for [jinchess board editor](http://www.jinchess.com/chessboard/composer/). So what I'm looking for is a board editor like this one but which gives me the option to edit the pieces set with some png image files I have for a personalized chess set.

I would love as well the possibility to change the board image.

My final aim would be to be able to create a chess position like the one bellow using a chess board editor and not having to copy and paste the image files with an image editor.

[image: Chess board with personalized chess set]

### To sum up

To sum up I look for a program or website which lets:

1. Create a chess board position.
2. Use custom piece set using personalized image files.
3. Use as board a personalized board image file.

**Note**: If not a website, the software I'm looking for can be for Mac, Windows, and/or Linux.

Comment: Actually the question you refer to asks for a program to play chess with different chess sets but doesn't talk about editting a board with personalized chess set. And on that question it appears the only answer by bow refers to a website that offers chess sets but not a chess program.

Comment: I may end up programming my own program for this but I was wandering if there may exist something already. I may use part of my project [8x8cam](http://iie.fing.edu.uy/investigacion/grupos/gti/timag/trabajos/2013/ajedrez/index.html) which was made in Matlab and write similar ideas in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly "custom" images but it has over 50 piece designs and 6 board sizes. You can make a "remix" version, as Scratch calls it and replace the piece designs with whatever you like, same goes with the board. The project is here: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/339815697/

Edit: I've made a new HD Version of this project, it only supports an 8x8 board size but there are now over 160 piece designs and all of them are fully HD! You can use it here: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/343444076/

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for but it's a nice start. Nice Scratch program indeed. I attempted to program a board editor in Python with vectorized pieces but got stuck in some difficulties using the [pychess](http://www.pychess.org/) api. I hope to get a definitive program and publish it here then.

Comment: One detail I would like is to be able to place the pieces centered in the chess squares. And also get a good resolution image as result.

Comment: Thanks and hope you can make your program soon! I'm not sure if I'll be able to add piece square centering as it would take a lot of time and coding, and I'm not the best at programming really.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can check [Lichess](https://www.lichess.org).
It has advanced board editor feature (along with study feature also). It uses stockfish 11 server analysis for analyzing the game, has massive database with millions of games and above all, it is completely FREE.
Go and check that out.

Comment: I'm also fan of lichess and it has a good board editor. But what I'm actually looking for is a program or web that provides me the option to select from a personalized chess set of pieces and not the preset pieces that comes with the program whatsoever.

Comment: I think, you then can go to chess.com. It has variety of theme as well as a powerful board editor. So I think, you'll definitely find that interesting.

Comment: Chess.com is neither a solution I want a theme of own, like the one in my question, not preset in chess.com.